# Replacing words in DataFrame row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:
[salesdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF3Pf.png)

I am trying to extract the model of each SUV into a new dataframe column. I am trying to replace the first instance of 'Rover' in the description of some of the rows in the model column. For example I have 'Rover Range Rover Sport SDV6 Luxury Auto 4x4 MY12' and I want to have 'Range Rover Sport SDV6 Luxury Auto 4x4 MY12'. I have tried the below code but it still returns 'Rover Range Rover Sport SDV6 Luxury Auto 4x4 MY12'.

```
salesdata['Modellst']=[list(x.split(' '))[2:] for x in salesdata['title']]
salesdata['Model']=[' '.join(x) for x in salesdata['Modellst']]
salesdata['Model'].replace(lambda x: x=='Rover','',inplace=True)
salesdata.drop(columns='Modellst',inplace=True)
salesdata['Model'].unique()
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the whole 'Rover Range Rover' with 'Range Rover'. Also, you have to use the series.str.replace method

```
salesdata['Model'].str.replace('Rover Range Rover', 'Range Rover')
```